# Questions about mobile cache, normal tables and basemaps

Tags: arcgis-10.1, cache, arcgis-mobile

we are piloting a data gathering application for Windows Mobile and have encountered a few challenges as we don't have previous experience with the ArcGIS Mobile. In future after the pilot, we would need to implement synchronization with a bigger system this application will be part of.

1) We have geodatabase, which contains some standalone tables that have no geometry. We need to be able to update those tables in the mobile application as well. Currently we are trying to create feature classes for each of these tables, add the data into those and then generate some fake geometry point for each row. Is there any other workaround or is this viable solution?

2) Is there any way to add background maps to the application without ArcServer? As I have understood, we need to publish a service in ArcServer and get background maps from the service. Is there any way to have, for example just a .tiff raster map in the device and use that as a background map in the application? This would make our lives much easier during this pilot phase...

3) Are there any known limitations with mobile cache? We have now created the feature classes for few tables and added fake geometries for those. We were able to generate mobile cache with those, but we saw data only for one table, which had only 3 rows. Another table had 14000 rows, and the data was not in mobile cache. The geometry creation had worked because we can see it in ArcMap using the identify tool.

4) Is mobile cache the only solution to save the data? It would be nice to have all the features and tables in one place and it feels such a hassle because we haven't found a way to save normal tables to cache. We are also investigating a way to have two databases, mobile cache and then another database for normal tables. But it feels like there must be easier way around this?

We are using ArcGIS Desktop 10 and ArcGIS Mobile 10.1.1

Thanks!

Comment: It's been 3 months since you asked your question. Did you find an answer yourself?